# card constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am pretty confused on how  to make this class properly. I do not know how to create an ArrayList with all of these mixed values...Any help would be appreciated.

```
public StandardCardImpl(Suit suit, int rank, StandardCardImpl deck) {
    face_up = false;

List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>(DeckSize);
        cards.add(suit,rank,deck);

    if (rank < 1 || rank > KING) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Rank is out of range for standard card");
    }
    Iterator iterator = cards.iterator();
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.deck = deck;
}
```

Comment: What is `Card`?  Can't it hold `suit`, `rank`, `deck`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start over.  What's a `Card`?  It is an object that has a rank and a suit.  So you need:

1. An `enum` named Suit.
2. A range of numbers for Ranks.  Probably 2 to 14 (10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace).

   - Or an enum: TWO, THREE, ..., ACE.  That might be a bit much.
3. A class `Card` that has a suit and rank.

`Card` should not have setters, as you don't want players to change a card when they have one. So,

```
public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final int rank;
    public Card(final Suit suit, final int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    // Getters, toString, equals, hashCode, formatting for humans, etc.
}
```

Now, you need to construct a deck. A deck should contain a list of cards, and you must be able to shuffle it.  You can make it an `ArrayList<Card>`, but I would make it an object that contains such a list, because decks have behavior. `deck.deal()` is clearer than doing what `deal` does inline.

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    public Deck() {
        for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) {
            for (int rank = 2; rank <= ACE; rank ++) {
                cards.add(new Card(suit, rank));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);  // Perhaps use your own Random too.
    }
    public synchronized Card deal() {
        Card dealt = cards.get(0);
        cards.remove(0);
        return dealt;
    }
}
```

There are all sorts of design decisions to be made here.

1. Should Rank be an enum too?  It makes the for loop easier.
2. Should building the deck be internal to the `Deck` class?  Suppose you want to handle not only poker and bridge but also pinochle or bezique, where there are 2 each of Ace-nine in each suit.
3. Should shuffling be tied to a cryptographic-quality RNG?
4. Should you use a `Stack` or `Deque` instead of an `ArrayList`?  `Stack` might be clearer, while `Deque`s can't be shuffled.
5. You have the idea of a card being face up or down.  That's an addition.  Playing solitaire?
6. What should `deal` do if the deck is empty?  That's a good reason to use a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the below?

```
cards.add(new Card(suit,rank,deck));
```

i.e Create a new `Card` object with the appropriate members, and then add that to the array list.